# programmatically sign into msn messenger

Tags: authentication, msn, messenger

How can I start up a msn messenger window, fill in the email and pass fields, and then 'press' the button 'sign in' programmatically using C#?

I want to do this because it would save me the hassle to do this all manually for 4 email addresses.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do some lighweight UI automation like explained here (with full sample) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163864.aspx